# How to resize any element along with siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-resizable

Please take a look of [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bibhaw/RJBTG/3/)
There is a `div` (dashed) which has three `div` (red, black & blue) inside of it. If i re-size dashed div, all three div re-size automatically but when i re size the red color div it only re-sizes but i want to fit into the container when i re-size the red div and vice-verse.

is there anyway to re-size any element along with change the siblings size in ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `alsoresize`

Have a look here [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/RJBTG/7/)

Comment: but i have such requirement where i need to set the size of parent ( container )

Comment: thanks kritya. yes it works let me put this code in my webApp but i am afraid whether it'll work or not. Actually i need to develop such coding which works like jsFiddle. Anyway you gave me an idea to do somehow. thanks again

Comment: Well this will certainly work :D Unless u put it like u have here

Answer (score 0):

one way of achievng this is at the time of writing the css codes u can put the height and width using the percentages like

```
height:70%;
width:80%;
```

so now when ull resize all the internals will get resized too